# What is causing this Polymer.dart to misbehave in Safari versus Chrome?

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

The (post `pub build`) app is at http://mycommunity.org.

Look at the console in both Safari and Chrome. In the former, there's:

```
[Error] Element name could not be inferred.
    b (polymer.js, line 12)
    (anonymous function) (mycommunity.org, line 5709)
[Error] Element name could not be inferred.
    b (polymer.js, line 12)
    (anonymous function) (mycommunity.org, line 5917)
[Error] Element name could not be inferred.
    b (polymer.js, line 12)
[Log] +WovenApp (index.html_bootstrap.dart.js, line 8353)
[Log] +AddStuff (index.html_bootstrap.dart.js, line 8353)
[Log] +InboxList (index.html_bootstrap.dart.js, line 8353)
[Error] SyntaxError: DOM Exception 12: An invalid or illegal string was specified. (platform.js, line 13)
[Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) (current-user, line 0)
[Error] TypeError: 'null' is not an object (evaluating 'String(a.constructor).match(/^\s*function\s*(\S*)\s*\(/)[1]') (index.html_bootstrap.dart.js, line 1283)
```

Comment: What versions of chrome and safari? Check out http://www.polymer-project.org/resources/compatibility.html

Comment: Safari Version 7.05. Chrome 36.

Comment: According to the chart, it should all be useable. And I should note it worked sometime ago, before some code changes. It's something specific to my setup, not to do with general compatibility.

Answer (score 2):

Wow, the culprit was this line which I now commented out. (I'm not even sure what the exact issue is with that line yet.)

https://github.com/DaveNotik/dart-stack/commit/5131fb225d068e23435759913f72d5346d4efc70#diff-53e52681924d78ddb4512d6f988c91cbR85

Hide yo kids, hide yo wives, your whole Polymer app can break without much notice and only after dart2js. Good ol' Git, I reset to the commit where it worked and identified the commit where it suddenly didn't and went through line by line.